# How to create multipart/mixed HTTPRequests in Scala (JSON+file)

Tags: scala, akka, content-type, akka-http

How can we create `multipart/mixed` requests in akka in the client?

`multipart/form-data` is 99% similar to `multipart/mixed`, however akka-http only provides convenience methods to the former and not the latter despite their similarities.

```
val jsonPayload = DataSourceSingleUploadRequest(
  "datasource-name",
  "datasource-username",
  "datasource-password",
)

import io.circe.generic.auto._, io.circe.syntax._

def createEntity: RequestEntity = {
  val fileFormPart = Multipart.FormData.BodyPart.fromPath("datasource", ContentTypes.`application/octet-stream`, Paths.get(extractFilePath))
  val jsonRequestFormPart = Multipart.FormData.BodyPart("request_payload", HttpEntity(ContentTypes.`application/json`, jsonPayload.asJson.noSpaces))

  Multipart.FormData(
    fileFormPart,
    jsonRequestFormPart
  ).toEntity()
}
```

The ideal way is to have `Multipart.MixedData`. I already attempted several solutions just to replace the mediaType but none of them were successful:

- The classes and traits are sealed so I can't override
- Can't create an custom implementation (reusing 99% of `Multipart-Formdata`) of the `Multipart` trait because the `Multipart.Formdata` uses private code.

Im short, I would like have help creating `multipart/mixed` requests that are 99% similar to `multipart/form-data`.

PS: the server does not really accept `multipart/form-data` :/

Edit: For completeness, `DataSourceSingleUploadRequest` is a case class and I am using circe

Answer (score 0):

Which version of akka-http are you using?

On [10.1.0-RC1](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/release-notes/10.1.x.html#10-1-0-rc1), I can see `Multipart.General.Strict` (it may be there on earlier versions, too).

Disclaimer: the code below compiles, but I haven't gotten to testing it, yet.

```
/*
* Create a Multipart/mixed message body
*/
private
def genMultipart( set: Set[MyEntry] ): Multipart.General.Strict = {
  import scala.collection.immutable.{Seq => ImmutableSeq}

  val parts: Set[Multipart.General.BodyPart.Strict] = set.map {
    case MyEntry(keys, ct, value) =>

      val headers: ImmutableSeq[HttpHeader] = ImmutableSeq(
        RawHeader("X-AC-key1", keys._1),
        RawHeader("X-AC-key2", keys._2)
      )
      Multipart.General.BodyPart.Strict(
        HttpEntity.Strict(ContentTypes.`text/plain(UTF-8)`, ByteString("1,2,3")),   // some random values
        headers
      )
  }

  Multipart.General.Strict( MediaTypes.`multipart/mixed`, parts.to[ImmutableSeq] )
}
```